# adding text as object to array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

The following program will add the text entered in input to an array and display the array in a `p` tag.  when the user press submit, the text will be added to the array.  I need to add it as an object containing index and text.

Currently, the array will look like: `['a', 'b', 'c']`

I need to the array to look like: `[{"index": 0, "text": "a"}, {"index": 1, "text": "b"}]`

```js
let arr = [];
function addText() {
    let text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    arr.push(text);
    res = document.getElementById('result-text').innerText = arr;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter a text" />
<input type="submit" onclick="addText()" />

<p id="result-text"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do

```
let arr = [];
function addText() {
    let text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    arr.push({ index: arr.length, text });
    res = document.getElementById('result-text').innerText = JSON.stringify(arr);
}
```

Comment: The p tag is displayed as [Object Object].  is there any way to display the data?

Comment: use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to string.

Comment: it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Just create the object and store it in an array

```js
let arr = [];
function addText() {
    let text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    let textObj = {
                     index: arr.size,
                     text: text
                  }
    arr.push(textObj);
    res = document.getElementById('result-text').innerText = arr;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter a text" />
<input type="submit" onclick="addText()" />

<p id="result-text"></p>
```

Comment: It is displayed as [object Object].  But, I need to display it as it is

Comment: refer the edit made by @TheWhiteFang

Answer (score 0):

Just use map:

```js
function addText() {
    const text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    const arr = text.split(',');
    const result = arr.map((text, index) => ({index, text}))
    document.getElementById('result-text').innerText = JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter a text" />
<input type="submit" onclick="addText()" />

<p id="result-text"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing text into the arr.
You can just manipulate it a bit like maintaining index variables and incrementing the same.

```js
let arr = [];
let index = 0;
function addText() {
    let text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    const obj = {index, text}
    arr.push(obj);
    res = document.getElementById('result-text').innerText = JSON.stringify(arr);
    index+=1
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter a text" />
<input type="submit" onclick="addText()" />

<p id="result-text"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the possible solution:

```js
let arr = [];
function addText() {
    let text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    let index = arr.length;
    arr.push({index:index,text:text});
    res = document.getElementById('result-text').innerText = JSON.stringify(arr);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter a text" />
<input type="submit" onclick="addText()" />

<p id="result-text"></p>
```